# React Native, how to change styles of button onPress and leave the style

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can i achieve a behaviour like this on the ios tasks app.
[image: ios tasks app]

where you can select one color, and it stays selected, showing that with a grey border.

Thank you for your answers! Im a noob,

Comment: I don't understand much about react-native, but can you to toggle a `class` on click?

Comment: you should show some codes at least.

Answer (score 1):

you can do component to btn with state.
const [isClicked,setIsClicked] = useState();

<Button onPress ={()=>setIsClicked(!isClicked)} style={{borderWidth:isClicked?1:0, borderColor:'grey' }}/>

something like that

Comment: And how can i make sure that you can only select one button at a time ?

Comment: you can give every button index, and save in the parent state which index is active.
in onPress, set the chosen index in the state